# Parallel computation of a quadratic term in Rcpp

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

Let Y and K be an n-dimensional (column) vector and n by n matrix, respectively. Think of Y and K as a sample vector and its covariance matrix. 
Corresponding to each entry of Y (say Y<sub>i</sub>) there is a row vector (of size 2) S<sub>i</sub> encoding the location of the sample in a two dimensional space. Construct the n by 2 matrix S by concatenating all the S<sub>i</sub> vectors. The ij-th entry of K is of the form

K<sub>ij</sub>= f( |s<sub>i</sub>-s<sub>j</sub>|, b )

in which |.| denotes the usual Euclidean norm, f is the covariance function and b represents the covariance parameters. For instance for powered exponential covariance we have f(x) = exp( (-|x|/r)<sup>q</sup> ) and b = (r,q).

The goal is to compute the following quantity in Rcpp, using a parallel fashion. (Y<sup>T</sup> stands for Y transpose and ||.||<sup>2</sup> denotes the sum of square entries of K).

Y<sup>T</sup>KY ⁄ ||K||<sup>2</sup>

Here is the piece of code I've written to do the job. While running, Rstudio runs out of memory after a few seconds and the following massage displays: "R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated". I've very recently started using open MP in Rcpp and I have no idea why this happens! Can anybody tell me what have I done wrong here?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<omp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

double InnerProd(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i]*y[i];
  }
  return total;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]

double CorFunc(double r, double range_param, double beta) {
  double q,x;
  x = r/range_param;
  q = exp( -pow(x,beta) );
  return(q);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]

double VarianceComp( double range, NumericVector Y, NumericMatrix s, double  
beta, int t ){

  int n,i,j;
  double  Numer = 0, Denom = 0, dist, CorVal, ObjVal;
  NumericVector DistVec;
  n = Y.size();
  omp_set_num_threads(t);

  # pragma omp parallel for private(DistVec,CorVal,dist,j) \
  reduction(+:Numer,Denom) 

  for( i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for( j = 0; j < n; ++j){
      DistVec = ( s(i,_)-s(j,_) );
      dist = sqrt( InnerProd(DistVec,DistVec) );
      CorVal = CorFunc(dist,range,beta);
      Numer += Y[i]*Y[j]*CorVal/n;
      Denom += pow( CorVal, 2 )/n;
    }  
  }
  ObjVal = Numer/Denom;
  return( ObjVal );
}
```

Comment: Are you telling us that it doesn't crash without the openmp pragma? What size input data?

Comment: Maybe you need to increase the size of the per-thread stack for accommodating the private copies of `DistVec`. Try setting up `OMP_STACKSIZE` to larger values and see what happens...